# Tableau splitting ranking without breaking the rank

Tags: tableau-api, ranking

I am trying to split a ranking table into two, but the problem is when I split it, the ranking is messed up.

See the images below. This is the ranking table before split

[image: This is the ranking table before split]

So, with the above table, I wanted to split with the Profit column. So, when the profit is above 10,000 then group one, other wise group 2.

Next 2 images are after split.

[image: split 1]
[image: split 2]

As you can see the second split image starts with 1 instead of 10.
How can I split it without messing up the ranking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate the Rank of Profit calc and use that to filter.

Below, rank of profit = `rank(sum([Profit]))`

[image]

[image]